# Cross Compile libdsm (C Library) for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to cross-compile a C Library known as [Libdsm](https://github.com/videolabs/libdsm). I want to generate .so files so that I can write a jni wrapper over it for further use in an Android project. I used the following commands to build it as explained by the authors of the library:

> $> ./bootstrap
>
> $> ./configure --prefix=/your/prefix
>
> $> make
>
> $> make install # maybe

After building it, I realized that the generated binary files won't work with android because of the difference in the architecture. 
How should I change the configurations so that the generated binary files become compatible to use in my Android project?

P.S.: I have gone through a couple of generic tutorials that use NDK & maybe a tool-chain to generate the .so files but I am not very familiar with those and when I try to do so I am constantly getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use the NDK's standalone toolchains: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used makefiles to build Android SOs (as the "official" NDK build process is truly awful)

You just need to use the correct compiler tools in the toolchains folder in your 
ANDROID_NDK folder (e.g. c:/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/). And add include paths to the appropriate include files in /sources/cxx-stl/, and libs in toolchain lib folder.

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
ifndef $(NDK_PLATFORM)
    NDK_PLATFORM = android-19
endif

ifndef $(GCC_VERSION)
    GCC_VERSION = 4.9
endif

ifndef $(GCC_TARGET)
    GCC_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi
endif

ifndef $(ARCH)
    ARCH=arch-arm
endif

SYS := $(shell gcc -dumpmachine)
ifndef $(TOOLS_PLATFORM)
ifneq (, $(findstring x86_64-apple-darwin, $(SYS)))
    TOOLS_PLATFORM=darwin-x86_64
else
ifneq (, $(findstring x86_64-redhat-linux, $(SYS)))
    TOOLS_PLATFORM=linux-x86_64
endif
    TOOLS_PLATFORM=windows-x86_64
endif
endif

ifndef $(ANDROID_PLATFORM)
    ANDROID_PLATFORM=armeabi-v7a
endif

TOOLCHAIN=$(GCC_TARGET)-$(GCC_VERSION)
CC_EXECUTABLE=$(GCC_TARGET)-gcc
CPP_EXECUTABLE=$(GCC_TARGET)-g++
SYS_ROOT=$(ANDROID_NDK)/platforms/$(NDK_PLATFORM)/$(ARCH)
PATH_LINK=$(SYS_ROOT)/usr/lib
TOOLCHAIN_BIN_FOLDER=$(ANDROID_NDK)/toolchains/$(TOOLCHAIN)/prebuilt/$(TOOLS_PLATFORM)/bin
TOOLCHAIN_LIB_FOLDER=$(ANDROID_NDK)/toolchains/$(TOOLCHAIN)/prebuilt/$(TOOLS_PLATFORM)/lib

STDC_FOLDER=$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/$(GCC_VERSION)
CC="$(TOOLCHAIN_BIN_FOLDER)/$(CPP_EXECUTABLE)"

NDK_INCLUDE_PATHS = -I "$(SYS_ROOT)/usr/include"
NDK_INCLUDE_PATHS += -I "$(STDC_FOLDER)/include" 
NDK_INCLUDE_PATHS += -I "$(STDC_FOLDER)/libs/$(ANDROID_PLATFORM)/include" 
NDK_INCLUDE_PATHS += -I "$(STDC_FOLDER)/include/backward" 
NDK_INCLUDE_PATHS += -I "$(TOOLCHAIN_LIB_FOLDER)/gcc/$(GCC_TARGET)/$(GCC_VERSION)/include"

NDK_LIB_PATHS = -Wl,-L"$(PATH_LINK)"
NDK_LIB_PATHS += -Wl,-L"$(TOOLCHAIN_LIB_FOLDER)/gcc/$(GCC_TARGET)/$(GCC_VERSION)/armv7-a"
NDK_LIB_PATHS += -Wl,-L"$(STDC_FOLDER)/libs/$(ANDROID_PLATFORM)/thumb" 



DEFS=-DANDROID -DDISABLE_OFURL -DTARGET_ANDROID -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
COPTS = -Werror --sysroot="$(SYS_ROOT)" -gdwarf-2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -mthumb -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -mfloat-abi=softfp -fstack-protector -fpic -fno-short-enums -frtti -std=c++1y -x c++ 

LDOPTS = -Wl,-rpath-link="$(PATH_LINK)" -Wl,--no-undefined --sysroot="$(SYS_ROOT)" -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack

ifeq ($(MODE),DEBUG)   
COPTS += -O0 -g3 -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG
else
COPTS += -O3 -s -DNDEBUG
LDOPTS += -O3 -s
endif
```

Other than that your makefile should work fine